# Creating a new JTable from current JTable view

Tags: view, filter, save, jtable, tablemodel

I am working on a project that involves JTable and performing sorting and filtering operations on it. I am done with the sorting and filtering part and now I want to be able to create a new table from the current view of older table.
e.g. If I apply certain filters to my old table, some rows are filtered out. I don't want those filtered out rows in my new table. I figured that I can convert the new row indices to model indices and add the cell values manually to new table's model, but I was wondering if there's any other efficient way to do this?
Following is what I ended up doing:

```
//this code block will print out the rows in current view
int newRowCount = table.getRowCount();
int newColumnCount = table.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 0; i < newRowCount; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < newColumnCount; j++) {
    int viewIndex = table.convertRowIndexToModel(i);
    String value = (String) model.getValueAt(viewIndex, j);
    System.out.print(value + "\t");

    }
    System.out.println();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need for any index conversion, simply ask query the table instead of the underlying model

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++) {
        Object value = table.getValueAt(i, j);
        System.out.print(value + "\t");
    }
}
```

Note: better rename the i/j to row/column for readability, was too lazy ;-)

Comment: Well, since some of the rows are filtered out and not displayed at all, the visible rows might map to a totally different index, so I guess we're going to need the index conversion anyways. (At least that is what I read after reading about the JTable javadocs). Still, I shall try your code as well. Thanks!  Note: replacing i/j by rowIndex/columnIndex is a good idea to make code readable and so is calling getRowCount() and getColumnCount() only once to make it more efficient, just occurred to me ;)

Comment: @user744820 as I understood it, you want a new model which contains the _visible_ rows of the old table. If that assumption is correct, the code snippet does what you want. If not, I misunderstood :-)